# Impossible to execute rails s | railties-5.2.3/exe/rails (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't launch my server with the command rails s, I have to use the command bundle exec rails s, but I prefer use the command rails s

**Error when I launch the command rails s**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from /home/leopaul/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
/home/leopaul/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/rails:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /home/leopaul/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/exe/rails (LoadError)
```

My rails version is :

```
Rails 5.1.6.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have multiple Rails versions installed in your machine.

Sometimes when you install a gem it comes with an executable/binary as well. Examples of these include: rails, rake, rspec, pry, etc. However, when you have multiple versions of a gem installed you then will have multiple versions of these executables sitting around. So if you want to execute one of these binaries for a given rails app you may need to disambiguate which executable you want -- the one for rake v10.1 or the one for rake v10.2, for example.

So for most commands you'll want to run bundle exec  to make sure you're running the right version for your project (and also to make sure that all dependencies are also loaded from the correct versions specified in your Gemfile.lock).

So answering to your question if you are able to do `bundle exec rails s` and unable to do `rails s` try reinstalling rails gem to your local machine.

```
gem install rails
```

then check current version by `rails -v`

Comment: I've gem uninstall rails like you said, there were a lot of versions and i've write in my gemfile the version of rails which is noted in gemfile.lock i've executed bundle install but when i use rails s i've the same problem so i'm oblige to use bundle exec rails s

Answer (score 0):

I would just like to add that in my case rubygems wasn't installed.

Running `sudo apt-get install rubygems` solved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

See docs: http://railsapps.github.io/updating-rails.html

It seems that you have installed globally is rails 4 or some other rails version and it's the reason "it doesn't execute rails s" like you say because it consider default(global rails version) rails. When you run bundle exec then it uses the rails commands from the current Gemfile, since you have rails 5 in your Gemfile then it works properly.

Also try to create gemsets for every project.

In case your case, try this:

```
bundle update
```

then excecute

```
rails s
```

Hope it will work :)

Comment: Now I can't even run bundle exec rails anymore ````Traceback (most recent call last):
        56: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
        55: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
        54: from /home/leopaul/Documents/rpdad/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
        53: from /home/leopaul/Documents/rpdad/bin/spring:15:in `require'
        52: from /home/leopaul/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-
      [...]
         1: from 5.1.6.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require': cannot load such file -- bindex (LoadError) ````

Comment: It is because of incompatible library version.  Run   'gem install bundler' and then 'bundle install' .  If it doesn't work, remove gemfile.lock and then bundle install again.  Then let me know.